# accessing the class Variable in function in python 3.3.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyserial

im new to python and i know there has been a lot of discussion on this but I still have a question. I am trying to access a variable from class to a same class function, its throughing a error as

***"AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isOpen'"***

Code is:

```
class serialCommunication():
    ser = 0               #class global variable
    def ser_port():
        .....
    def ser_Burdrate():
        BurdRate = ( "4800",
                     "9600",
                     "19200",
                     "38400",
                     "57600",
                     "115200"
                     )
        BR = int(input("Enter the Burd Rate\n0\t--\t4800\n1\t--\t9600\n2\t--\t19200\n3\t--\t38400\n4\t--\t57600\n5\t--\t115200\n\n"))
        return Portno , int(BurdRate[BR]), timeout
    def ser_open():
        port = serialCommunication.ser_Burdrate()
        serialCommunication.ser = serial.Serial(port[0], port[1], timeout=port[2])
        port = serialCommunication.ser.getPort()
        print (serialCommunication.ser , '\r\n')
        .....
    def ser_Write():

        if (serialCommunication.ser.isOpen()):
            print ('open: ', serialCommunication.ser.getPort())
        elif (serialCommunication.ser.closed()):
            serialCommunication.ser_open()
```

please advice on the same

### thanks in advance

thanks for advice i changed

```
ser = serial.Serial()
```

and it's throughing a error as

**"TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable"**

in if statement the bool object can be executed right..?

Comment: `ser` should be the instance of `serial.Serial()` and not `0`, if you will show your main and `ser_port()` it will be easier to help you.

Comment: def ser_port():
        COMnu = []
        available = []          #variable to com port
        for i in range(256):
            try:
                s = serial.Serial(i)
                available.append('COM'+str(i + 1))
                s.close()
                COMnu.append(i)
            except serial.SerialException:
                    pass
        #return available, COMnu
        return COMnu

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call a method .isOpen() on a int type (ser = 0 declared in the class serialCommunication) as the error suggests the object does not have this method.

I can't see the rest of the class but are you sure you shouldn't be trying to reference a method of the class directly? Also without an instance the method you call would need to be a class method prefixed with @classmethod decorator.

Comment: sorry, juyst realised what you are trying to do, ignore my second bit

Comment: i to released that im initializing the variable as int, i changed

ser = serial.Serial()

now it through the error as 

"TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable"

Comment: what ever you set ser to it needs to have the method isOpen() to work. serial.Serial() is setting ser to a boolean type so you can't call it. I know I'm just repeating the error but it really is that simple.